# way to use rapidminer clustering model using C#

Tags: c#, integration, data-mining, cluster-analysis, rapidminer

I have a process in rapidminer that applied k mean clustering on my provided excel sheet records.
Now I want that when I add some new record from c# desktop application, it uses that trained model to generate its appropriate cluster id.
Please suggest me some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you read up on how k-means clustering works?

Assigning new instances to fixed means from a previous run is trivial to implement yourself.

Comment: No, I have to use rapid miner for it. In short I want to use the trained model of rapid miner for new instances from C# desktop application.